# Can I connect Transformer Pad TF103C-A1 to an external monitor

Tags: usb

Any chance to mirror the screen of an Asus Transformer Pad TF103C-A1 to an external monitor? It can't be any type of an airplay, I need a wired connection. As the unit does not have an HDMI port the real question if it would work with a USB to VGA adapter.

Comment: A USB to VGA is preferred but a USB to HDMI would be ok as well if it works.